# How to wake up SIM800 module from sleep, after entering sleep mode 2 (AT+CSCLK=2)?

Tags: gsm, sleep, sim900

I want my SIM800 module (I interfaced it with Arduino Uno) to enter sleepmode-2 (I used AT+CSCLK=2 command). My question is, how do I wake it up from sleep? I tried giving various AT commands but I cannot see anything on the Arduino Terminal.

Comment: https://www.elecrow.com/download/SIM800%20Series_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.09.pdf

Read the AT+CSCLK description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with AT+CSCLK=2. Module wakes up with AT commands sent to the serial port of the module. No interaction with DTR pin except it needs to be high.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/223-sim900-sim800-sleep-mode-at-commands), to wake it up, you need to send any AT command, which will be ignored by the module (so no response), followed (within 5 seconds) by

> AT+CSCLK=0

It took me all of one minute to find that by Googling "SIM800 sleep wake".

Comment: Yes, but it does not work, The module ignores both DTR and communication on serial line after entering sleep mode

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but actual topic...Sleep mode 1 is made to enter and leave the sleep mode using the DTR pin.
You can use it in this way:

- DTR is LOW
- **PREPARE** the module with +CSCLK=1 ("AT+CSCLK=1\r")
- DTR goes HIGH -> SLEEP
- DTR goes LOW -> WAKE UP

To save more power +CFUN=0 before SLEEP and +CFUN=1 after WAKE UP.

Greetz
Putzlicht

Comment: Adding an answer to an old question is frowned upon around here. It is a better practice to ask a new question with a link to the old question.

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Don't listen to Dan!

Answer (score 1):

The second AT needs to follow the first within 50 ms. This could be AT+CSCLK=0 if you want the SIM800 to stay awake. You don't want it napping when you are waiting for it to confirm a connection. I think the DTR pin needs to be held high too and if you arrange that via a GPIO pin you can use AT+CSCLK=1.